# Process to get developer certificate

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I have searched a lot n found many way to get developer certificate, and now very much confused. 
I have applied for this on behalf of my company and at last I got a page with this message:

"**Thank you for submitting your enrollment**
Your application is now being processed

Program: iOS Developer Program
Name:Vivek Kumar JainEmail:vivek@matrixnmedia.com
Next steps: Company verification process

We will be verifying your company's identity. If necessary, we may ask for additional information in order to complete the review of your enrollment. We appreciate your patience as this process may take several days.
We will be contacting the legal representative you provided to verify that you have the legal authority to bind your company to any agreements that may be presented to you as part of the enrollment process or during your membership.
You can check the status of your enrollment at any time by visiting the Member Center.
Once we have completed the review process, you will receive an email from Apple Developer Support with further instructions.
While we process your enrollment, please visit the Member Center to access development resources currently available to you."

Now from last many days daily I login and visit to its Member Center and got the same message:

"**Your Developer Program Enrollment Status**
We are processing your Program Enrollment and are attempting to reach the legal contact you provided during the enrollment process."

Plz anyone can verify whether I have followed the right way ?
If its right then how many days it can be take to complete enrollment process?
After this process, will we get developer certificate?
When we have to pay $99 ?

Plz guide me for right way.

Comment: This sounds like a question to e-mail to the support/customer service people at the company you bought the certificate from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can take anywhere from a few days to several months, depending on how difficult it is for them to verify your company details. Normally it would be finished within a week.

Comment: ok, means I followed the right way. After this enrollment will I get developer certificate n how many days it will take for provide certificate and when we have to pay $99 ?

Comment: Once they have processed your request you can generate the certificates you need yourself, it only takes a minute or so.
Once you are admitted you will have opportunity to pay. See more here as well: http://developer.apple.com/support/ios/identity-verification.html

Comment: Till now I didn't get my answer and more confused after reading enamrik's edited answer.

Comment: Yes, but he just stated he was wrong. You have applied for the right thing if you wish to develop apps for the AppStore.

Answer (score 2):

It should only take a few hours ~24 - 48 ... you dont get a "certificate", rather, you get online access to the developer portal.

Comment: Only a few hours if you applied as an individual, when applying as company (as it looks like Archana did) it usually takes quite a bit longer in my experience.

Comment: ok, u mean to say after enrollment we will get access to developer portal and from there we can generate certificate. and What about payment ?

Comment: @Pål Brattberg and WrightsCS : Ya I have applied as a company.

Comment: @ArchanaChaurasia I got same issue.How you resolve this issue.Please let me know

Answer (score 1):

1. Creating an Apple id using your company domain.
2. Requesting a unique D-U-N-S number or checking if you already have one.
3. Enrolling as a company for the Apple developer program using your company’s
4. Paying for the Apple developer program.
5. Activating your Apple developer program.

Answer (score 0):

Took over a week for mine when I signed up for [BEAM](http://beam.biz/app) but I believe mine was longer as it was rolled out just after WWDC. Try to avoid peak periods